# How can I get long value of event Id from Event object?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I was using Google Calendar API to get the events. After I got the events,the Event object doesn't contain long value of event id. I want to use the event id for view event details via Google Calendar app.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

```
  compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
  }
```

I was using the method, but I think that is not a good practice.

```
private static final String[] INSTANCE_PROJECTION = new String[]{
        CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_ID,      // 0
        CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN,         // 1
        CalendarContract.Instances.END,         // 1
        CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE          // 2
};

private static final int PROJECTION_ID_INDEX = 0;
private static final int PROJECTION_BEGIN_INDEX = 1;
private static final int PROJECTION_END_INDEX = 2;
private static final int PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX = 3;

public long getEventId(String title) {

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
            INSTANCE_PROJECTION,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    long eventIDL = 0;
    long beginVal = 0;
    long endVal = 0;
    String _title = null;
    int size = cursor.getCount();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        // Get the field values
        eventIDL = cursor.getLong(PROJECTION_ID_INDEX);
        beginVal = cursor.getLong(PROJECTION_BEGIN_INDEX);
        endVal = cursor.getLong(PROJECTION_END_INDEX);
        _title = cursor.getString(PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX);

        if (beginVal == eventDate.getDateStart() && endVal == eventDate.getDateEnd()) {
            if (title != null && _title != null) {
                if (title.equals(_title)) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (title == null && _title == null) {
                break;
            }

            if (title == null && _title != null && _title.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }

            if (title != null && title.isEmpty() && _title != null && _title.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return eventIDL;
}
```

Comment: Just a guess. Did you try converting the String to Long. Long.valueOf(String) to get Long Object or Long.parseLong(String) to get long value

Comment: String id = Event.getId(); 
the id = r1c59vmilhkmgli7ski901h;